# Hyperparameter Tuning for XGBoost multi-output regressor

Tags: python, boosting, hyperparameter, error-message, tuning

I'm trying to tune hyperparameters for XGBoost using RandomizedSearchCV. I have five outputs and I guess that might be the reason that I can't run RandomizedSearchCV or GridSearchCV to tune hyperparameters. Running this code:

```
params = { 'max_depth': [3, 5, 6, 10, 15, 20],
           'learning_rate': [0.01, 0.1, 0.2, 0.3],
           'subsample': np.arange(0.5, 1.0, 0.1),
           'colsample_bytree': np.arange(0.4, 1.0, 0.1),
           'colsample_bylevel': np.arange(0.4, 1.0, 0.1),
           'n_estimators': [100, 500, 1000]}

xgbr = xgb.XGBRegressor(seed = 20)

clf = RandomizedSearchCV(estimator=xgbr,
                         param_distributions=params,
                         scoring='neg_mean_squared_error',
                         n_iter=25,
                         verbose=1)

clf.fit(X_train, Y_train)
print("Best parameters:", clf.best_params_)
print("Lowest RMSE: ", (-clf.best_score_)**(1/2.0))
```

I get this error:

```
UserWarning: One or more of the test scores are non-finite: [nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan
 nan nan nan nan nan nan nan]
  warnings.warn(
```

Is having multiple outputs in Y_train the cause of this issue?

Comment: sklearn's mse handles multioutput, by default just averaging the mse's of each output.  Whenever scoring fails in a hyperparameter search, set `error_score="raise"` so you can see the traceback of the error.

Comment: @BenReiniger yes, I have already used mse to evaluate my model with no issues. The problem is no tuning method works for multiple outputs. I'm not sure if I have missed something here.

Comment: The docs for `RandomizedSearchCV.fit` say that `y` can have shape `(n_samples, n_output)`, so it should work for multioutput.  Try getting the full error traceback as mentioned before, and/or provide a minimal example (dataset) that produces the error.

Answer (score 0):

I guess it might be an incompatibility between the parameters in `params`.

The output you are getting is caused by a regressor that is generating answers that are not a number, ex: 1/eps where eps can be a very small number.

You have to check fewer params first to see where the problem lies.